# AWK Attempt to use scalar variable as an array error

Tags: awk

- I am using the following script:

```
    #!/usr/bin/awk -f
    BEGIN {
        FS = "[_.]"
    }
    
    function display() {
        if (length(gene_ids) > 1)
            for (j=0; j <= i; j++)
                print a[j]
    }
    
    {
        if (/^>Cluster /) {
            display()
            delete a
            delete gene_ids
            a[i=0] = $0
        } else {
            a[++i] = $0
            gene_ids[$7] = 1
        }
    }
    
    END {
        display()
    }
```

- To process the following file:

```
>Cluster 0
0   3843aa, >9606_9d1c13f4f2796e1bc5d9c034d256608e_ENSP00000478752_3843_318_ENST00000621744_ENSG00000286185... *
1   3843aa, >9606_9d1c13f4f2796e1bc5d9c034d256608e_ENSP00000498781_3843_318_ENST00000651566_ENSG00000271383... at 1:3843:1:3843/100.00%
>Cluster 17
0   1388aa, >9606_e3f5b4b466cd2bae95842b586d4d5ff5_ENSP00000419786_1388_4_ENST00000465301_ENSG00000243978... *
1   1388aa, >9606_e3f5b4b466cd2bae95842b586d4d5ff5_ENSP00000441452_1388_4_ENST00000540313_ENSG00000243978... at 1:1388:1:1388/100.00%
>Cluster 34
0   1150aa, >9606_c6fca1c116a00dbb0d2e8930f4056625_ENSP00000353655_1150_26_ENST00000360468_ENSG00000196547... *
1   1150aa, >9606_c6fca1c116a00dbb0d2e8930f4056625_ENSP00000452948_1150_26_ENST00000559717_ENSG00000196547... at 1:1150:1:1150/100.00%
>Cluster 39
0   1072aa, >9606_64cead9c681fd594c83c17cc06748bb6_ENSP00000315112_1072_50_ENST00000324103_ENSG00000092098... *
1   1072aa, >9606_64cead9c681fd594c83c17cc06748bb6_ENSP00000457512_1072_50_ENST00000558468_ENSG00000259529... at 1:1072:1:1072/100.00%
>Cluster 271
0       551aa, >9606_95dbfd3f219d32f1cc1074a79bfc576d_ENSP00000415200_551_42_ENST00000429354_ENSG00000268500... *
1       551aa, >9606_95dbfd3f219d32f1cc1074a79bfc576d_ENSP00000470259_551_42_ENST00000599649_ENSG00000268500... at 1:551:1:551/100.00%
2       551aa, >9606_95dbfd3f219d32f1cc1074a79bfc576d_ENSP00000473238_551_42_ENST00000534261_ENSG00000105501... at 1:551:1:551/100.00%
>Cluster 284
0       547aa, >9606_8ed59e1e16a1229b55495ff661b5aa66_ENSP00000354675_547_9_ENST00000361229_ENSG00000198908... *
1       547aa, >9606_8ed59e1e16a1229b55495ff661b5aa66_ENSP00000361820_547_9_ENST00000372735_ENSG00000198908... at 1:547:1:547/100.00%
2       547aa, >9606_8ed59e1e16a1229b55495ff661b5aa66_ENSP00000391722_547_9_ENST00000448867_ENSG00000198908... at 1:547:1:547/100.00%
3       547aa, >9606_8ed59e1e16a1229b55495ff661b5aa66_ENSP00000403226_547_9_ENST00000457056_ENSG00000198908... at 1:547:1:547/100.00%
4       547aa, >9606_8ed59e1e16a1229b55495ff661b5aa66_ENSP00000405893_547_9_ENST00000447531_ENSG00000198908... at 1:547:1:547/100.00%
```

- Which results in the following output:

```
>Cluster 0
0   3843aa, >9606_9d1c13f4f2796e1bc5d9c034d256608e_ENSP00000478752_3843_318_ENST00000621744_ENSG00000286185... *
1   3843aa, >9606_9d1c13f4f2796e1bc5d9c034d256608e_ENSP00000498781_3843_318_ENST00000651566_ENSG00000271383... at 1:3843:1:3843/100.00%
>Cluster 39
0   1072aa, >9606_64cead9c681fd594c83c17cc06748bb6_ENSP00000315112_1072_50_ENST00000324103_ENSG00000092098... *
1   1072aa, >9606_64cead9c681fd594c83c17cc06748bb6_ENSP00000457512_1072_50_ENST00000558468_ENSG00000259529... at 1:1072:1:1072/100.00%
>Cluster 271
0       551aa, >9606_95dbfd3f219d32f1cc1074a79bfc576d_ENSP00000415200_551_42_ENST00000429354_ENSG00000268500... *
1       551aa, >9606_95dbfd3f219d32f1cc1074a79bfc576d_ENSP00000470259_551_42_ENST00000599649_ENSG00000268500... at 1:551:1:551/100.00%
2       551aa, >9606_95dbfd3f219d32f1cc1074a79bfc576d_ENSP00000473238_551_42_ENST00000534261_ENSG00000105501... at 1:551:1:551/100.00%
```

- The script works like a charm on my test machine (running GNU Awk 5.1.0, API: 3.0). But when I attempt to run the script on my production machines (either running GNU Awk 5.1.0, or GNU Awk 4.1.4), the script gives me the following error:

```
(FILENAME=test_cluster FNR=1) fatal: attempt to use scalar `gene_ids' as an array
```

- I have tested if the error is related to the `length(array)` by running the following:

```
awk 'BEGIN{a[1]=10;a[2]=20;print length(a)}'
```

as suggested [here](http://awk.freeshell.org/AwkFeatureComparison)

- But this gives me the expected result in all my machines.
- I have also tested if the state of the `posix` variable, using the following code:

```
set -o | grep posix
```

- But these tests give me the same result (off) in all my machines.
- Giving that my production machines are all running Ubuntu server 18.01, I have also tested using AWK on an Ubuntu 20.01 server machine, but the result was the same (not successful).
- Also, giving that my test machine (running GNU Awk 5.1.0), is a MacOS with AWK installed via MacPorts, I have tried compiling AWK on my Ubuntu machines using the same configuration command, but while the compilation worked, running the script using this newly compiled AWK also gave me the same error.
- I would appreciate any help that would identify the origin of the problem and possible solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`length(gene_ids)` declares `gene_ids` as a scalar if `gene_ids` is previously unused because historically `length()` was used only on strings (that behavior will change in a upcoming gawk release such that `length()` won't set the type of it's argument if it was previously unset).

Add `delete gene_ids` to the BEGIN section to declare it as an array regardless of the order in which the existing lines of your script get hit, which is driven by your input data:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{ length(gene_ids); gene_ids[1] }'
awk: cmd. line:1: fatal: attempt to use scalar `gene_ids' as an array

$ awk 'BEGIN{ delete gene_ids; length(gene_ids); gene_ids[1] }'
$
```